# How to change the format of a date in a .csv file

Tags: csv, date, format

I have a .csv file that I need to read into R, with the current date in the format "YYYY-mm-dd". I need to convert all the dates to "yyyymmdd" and re-write the .csv file. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: So basically, all you need to do is replace the dashes in the date fields.. Something like `str_replace(<TheDateField>, "-", "")` ?

Comment: Thanks Theo, the command ran however it only removed the first dash between the year and month.

Comment: I see.. Try `str_replace_all(string = "<TheDateField>", pattern = "-", replacement = "")`

Comment: Perfect thank you!